# Configuring Intellisense in ICSharpCode.TextEditor

Tags: c#, intellisense, icsharpcode

I can't understand how to let Intellisense work in `ICSharpCode.TextEditor`. As of today, replies are incomplete. On the web, there are no samples...

I need to display a completion box with my custom keywords.

Any help?

Comment: Ayende has a simple example: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/21/Basic-intellisense.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a couple weeks ago and grabbed the sample app for ICSharpCode texteditor CodeComplete and was able to consolidated it all into one file

See here for my first pass at it: https://github.com/o2platform/FluentSharp_Fork.SharpDevelopEditor/blob/master/FluentSharp.SharpDevelopEditor/_O2SharpDevelop/CodeCompletion/O2CodeCompletion.cs

My objective at that stage was to create one file will all dependencies so that I could (for example) add code complete to any TextEditorControl control (I also had to make a couple changes to allow dynamic code complete updates from multiple source code files)

To use the O2ComdeCompletion.cs object just call:

o2CodeCompletion = new O2CodeCompletion( {your instance of TextEditorControl} );

Comment: The link is no longer active. I have implemented my own version but would love to have an ogle at yours if you would be so kind? Could you post the code again, or send me a copy? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Both links are no longer active

Comment: Hi @Jack, sorry about that, I just fixed the main link and here are the ones that were on the comments: http://blog.diniscruz.com/p/owasp-o2-platform.html and http://blog.diniscruz.com/p/c-repl-script.html